# Python tkinter "KeyPress" and "KeyRelease" events not working properly

Tags: python, tkinter, text-editor

I am working on an small editor based on python Tkinter library. While adding the autocomplete feature, I noticed an odd behaviour.

Okay, so lets come to the autocomplete part. The autocomplete function is based on two tkinter Text widget events "KeyPress" and "KeyRelease". The autocomplete TopLevel window will show up on "KeyRelease" and it will disappear on "KeyPress" in the main Text Widget. This basically works in most cases, but it often happens that the autocomplete window gets stuck on the window and does not get hidden.

The screenshot of the window is below:
[image]

Here is the code for Autocomplete window class:

```
class AcompWindow:

def __init__(self, widget, lst=[]):
    self.waittime = 500     #miliseconds
    self.wraplength = 180   #pixels
    self.widget = widget
    self.lst = lst
    self.id = None
    self.tw = None


def show(self, event=None, lst=[]):
    """
    lst: Completion list
    """

    ## if top.get(): self.hidetip()

    x = y = 0
    x, y, _, _ = self.widget.bbox("insert")
    x += self.widget.winfo_rootx() + 25
    y += self.widget.winfo_rooty() + 20
    # creates a toplevel window
    self.tw = tk.Toplevel(self.widget)
    # Leaves only the label and removes the app window
    self.tw.wm_overrideredirect(True)
    self.tw.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

    frame = self.tw

    self.listNodes = tk.Listbox(frame, height=6, font=("Helvetica", 12), bg="#083112160", fg="white")
    self.listNodes.pack(side="left", fill="y")

    # listbox scrollbar
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical")
    scrollbar.config(command=self.listNodes.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    ## scrollbar.focus()

    self.listNodes.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    # appending comp list to list box
    for x in lst:
            self.listNodes.insert(tk.END, str(x))

    # selection vars
    self.selection = 0
    self.listNodes.select_set(self.selection)
    top.set(0)


def hide(self, event=None):
    """Hide the Completion window """
    top.set(1)
    tw = self.tw
    self.tw = None
    if tw:
        tw.destroy()
```

And here is shorted version of the main Text Window class:

```
class Text_window(tk.Text):
"Main text window. "
def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):

    self.text = self

    super(Text_window, self).__init__(master=master)

    self.configure(highlightbackground='yellow', bg="#1E1E1E", fg="#FFFFFF")



    # initilizing completion window.
    self.tool = Acompwindow(self)
    self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.complete)
    self.bind("<KeyPress>", self.tool.hidetip)

def complete(self, event):
    self.update_idletasks()
    self.lst = []

    comp_list = getcompletions(self) # getcompletion func not included

    if comp_list:
        self.tool.showtip(lst=comp_list)
```

Note: I am not including the full code for some private reasons.

Comment: When the autocomplete window is shown, the `Text_window` may lost the key focus and so the `KeyPress` event will not be triggered.

Comment: @acw1668 Nope. The text window is always on focus. Otherwise I could not continue typing. And also it happens only some times, not always.